# java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out (Connection timed out) while connecting mysql docker from local machine

Tags: java, mysql, scala, docker, apache-spark

Im trying to connect to a mysql container thats running on local maching using a scala code. For some reason Im getting either operation time out(dockerIp) or connection refused error(localhost/127.0.0.1).

```
docker run --name=mysql-docker -p3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='root' -d mysql:latest
docker exec -it mysql-docker bash
mysql -u root -p
update mysql.user set host = ‘127.0.0.1’ where user=’root’;
```

Im able to connect to docker from terminal using `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root -p`

Below is my scala code.

```
  val url = "jdbc:mysql://172.17.0.2:3006/mysql"
  val driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  val username = "root"
  val password = "root"
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
  val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password)
  val statement = connection.createStatement
  val rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT host, user FROM user")
  connection.close
```

Unfortunately this code throws the

```
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:828)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:448)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
        at largedataprocessor.LargeDataProcessor$.delayedEndpoint$largedataprocessor$LargeDataProcessor$1(LargeDataProcessor.scala:35)
        at largedataprocessor.LargeDataProcessor$delayedInit$body.apply(LargeDataProcessor.scala:9)
        at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:39)
        at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:39)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:17)
        at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
        at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:431)
        at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
        at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
        at largedataprocessor.LargeDataProcessor$.main(LargeDataProcessor.scala:9)
        at largedataprocessor.LargeDataProcessor.main(LargeDataProcessor.scala)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:89)
        at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:119)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:948)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:818)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:156)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63)
        ... 20 more
```

Instead if i use "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3006/mysql", I get a connection refused error.

Please point out my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Network-wise, some dockerized process is running on a different host than non-dockerized ones. So connecting to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` within the container will connect back to the same container where nothing is listening on port 3306 - you correctly get `connection refused`.

If you try to connect to your host's IP on port 3306 you may either

- get a connection refused if your mysql is listening to localhost:3306 only
- get a timeout if your host's firewall is preventing the access

Be sure to configure both items before expecting success.

Another option would be to run your container on the host-network. Then there is no need to expose the port (it is exposed anyway), and connecting to localhost should give you the expected effect.

You may want to get more familiar with [Docker networking](https://docs.docker.com/network/).

Edit: So far I tried to explain why you perceive the results you mentioned. Everything is working as designed. So now let's figure out what you need to do to get connectivity:

- be aware that 127.0.0.1 will not work
- configure mysql inside the container to listen to 0.0.0.0:3306
- run the container with -p 3306:3306
- open your host's firewall to allow traffic on :3306
- run your client application and try to connect to :3306

Comment: The application is running in my local, its not in container. And the mysql containers ip is 172.17.0.2, using that gives the time out error. When you say hosts firewall does it mean macs firewall ?

Comment: Actually by dockerized application I was referring to your mysql. Now edited to make it more neutral. Does it apply now?

Comment: OKay got that part. What about 2nd point, host firewall preventing access? How do I get around that ? Also you mentioned to run container on host network (i assume mysql), but am i not doing that already, i mean by exposing the port?

Comment: Today many operating systems come with a firewall activated by default. To not show attackers that there is a machine that can be attacked, they prevent 'connection refused' messages unless being told otherwise. You are connecting to the IP/Port that is visible from outside of your machine - hence the firewall might catch the packets and decide to not respond. Depending on what system you run you will simply have to reconfigure it to allow the traffic.

Comment: oh okay, Ive come across this point earlier with many others facing same thing, but none of the solutions really worked. Do you know any way to get around this? Funny thing is Im able to connect to the container using the mysql client from my terminal, but not through the scala code using driver.

Comment: How do you run the mysql client? If it like you mentioned in the question, you are running the client INSIDE the container. As I understood your scala code is OUTSIDE on the host. Follow the instructions I added to my response to connect from outside the container.

Comment: Installed mysql-client and ran the command mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root -p from terminal. (not from the containers bash) this connects to the mysql container. So isnt this connection outside the container ?

Comment: If that already works TCP connections from outside the container to your database are possible. In that case just investigate why your scala application does not perform the same TCP connection as the mysql client.